# how to escape double quotes and single quotes mixed up in python fabric

Tags: python, postgresql, fabric

i have bash command with two double quotes and one single quotes like this :

```
sudo su - postgres bash -c "psql -c \"ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '00000000001';\" "
```

when i run this in terminal everything is OK .

but when i use this in python fabric, every time it return syntax error

```
run('''echo sudo su - postgres bash -c "psql -c \"ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '00000000003';\" " ''')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a raw string to ensure that the backslashes stay as literal backslashes and aren't interpreted by Python:

```
run(r'''echo sudo su ...''')
```